# returning a pointer to an array of objects

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, scope

I'm having trouble returning a pointer to an array of objects, specifically how to define the return type and I just can't get the pointer to return...

```
month* year()
{
    month* p;

    month arr[12] = { month(31), month(28), month(31), month(30),  month(31), month(30), month(31), month(31), month(30), month(31), month(30), month(31) };

    p = arr;

    return p;
}
```

I've also been experimenting on the side and I'm worried even if I get it to return, can I still access the objects from main? This only lets me access the first element (not first element, first I try to access) I choose to and the won't give me the contents:

```
int** createArray()
{
    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 2;
    int n3 = 3;

    int* p[3];

    p[0] = &n1;
    p[1] = &n2;
    p[2] = &n3;

    int** j = p;

    return j;
}

int main()
{
    int** point = createArray();
    *point[2] = 5;
    cout << *point[1] << endl;
    cout << *point[2] << endl;
}
```

Update: I should have mentioned I have to use arrays and pointers in this project for my course. I understand my (foolish) mistake regarding the local variables but even if I make it into a class I have the same problem with the return type:

```
class create {
public:
    month* GetArr();
    create();
private:
    month arr[12];
    month* arrP;

};

create::create(){
    month arr[12] = { month(31), month(28), month(31), month(30), month(31), month(30), month(31), month(31), month(30), month(31), month(30), month(31)};
    month* arrP = arr;
}

month* create::GetArr()
{
    return arrP;
}
```

Comment: Do not use raw pointers or raw arrays in c++ please.

Comment: don't. As soon as you return from the function your array stops existing. It is allocated on stack of the called function which does not exist after the return. So, the pointer would point to invalid memory. Use `malloc` or `new`.

Comment: @user0042 Why not?

Comment: If you're new, don't use pointers . It is much easier to code without them. You would not encounter any of the problems you have experienced in this thread.

Comment: @Serge Because c++ already has containers and smart pointers..Raw pointers and arrays are simply error prone, and most of the people fail to get them right.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is that you're returning a pointer to a local object, and that object gets destroyed as soon as your function ends, so then the pointer is pointing to garbage.

```
month* year()
{
    month* p;
    month arr[12] = { month(31), month(28), month(31), month(30),  month(31), month(30), month(31), month(31), month(30), month(31), month(30), month(31) };
    p = arr;
    return p;
}
```

Once `year()` ends, `arr` is invalid. What you want to use instead is a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<month> year()
{
    std::vector<month> months = { month(31), month(28), month(31), month(30),  month(31), month(30), month(31), month(31), month(30), month(31), month(30), month(31) };
    return months;
}
```

Now you'll return a container to all the months:

```
struct month
{
     month(int d) : days(d) {}
     int numberOfDays() const { return days; }
 private:
     int days;
};

int main()
{
    auto months = year();
    for (auto m : months)
        std::cout << "Days in month: " << m.numberOfDays() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is I have to use an array for my assignment and I also need to use a pointer...This was my simplest solution but I foolishly forgot the array would be deleted. Could I just create a new class that does what I did in this function?

Comment: If you **have** to use an array, then it would've been worth mentioning in the question and as an aside whatever course you're doing sounds rubbish. There are plenty of ways to use an array and a pointer. Making `arr` `static` would work, but that'd be a poor design. You could make a class that creates the array, so it's alive for longer than the local function. You could pass an array to the function and have it populate the elements. Everything is basically inferior to the use of `vector`

Comment: Except [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) which would be more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with how you are returning your memory. The issue is that the pointer you are returning is pointing to a variable which was created in the local variable space of that function (known as its stack frame). When you return out of that function, that stack frame is "destroyed" and you can no longer access it. In reality it is not actually destroyed and that is why you might be able to access it (but this is very dangerous). To get around this you must create some memory which is not inside the stack frame of your function and then return a pointer to that.

Here are some good explanations of dynamic memory:

[more to the point](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/)

[better explanation](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/69-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-new-and-delete/)

Comment: If you use a std::vector as suggested by @Tas, all of the dynamic memory stuff will be done for you in the background. But I think as a new learner you should really have a crack at doing it yourself.